# Prove that if $B$ is open then $B\cap \bar{A}\subset\overline{A\cap B}$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

How can I prove that if $A,B\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $B$ is open then $B\cap \bar{A}\subset\overline{A\cap B}$ using balls?

I've seen [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3027499/967766) proof:

> Let $x\in {\overline A}\cap B$. Since $B$ is open, we can chose
> $r>0$ such that $B_{r}(x)\subset B$. For some $0 < s < r$ we still have
> $B_s(x)\cap B\neq\emptyset$ and since $x\in\overline A$, then
> $B_s(x)\cap A\neq\emptyset$. Thus $B_s(x)\cap(A\cap B)\neq\emptyset$.
>
> We have just shown $x\in \overline{A \cap B}.$

but it seems wrong since $s$ isn't arbitrary. The following is my attempt at a proof but I suppose it's also wrong since I don't use the fact that $B$ is open. Why is it wrong?

Let $x\in B\cap\overline{A}$. Then since $x\in\overline{A}$, we have that $\forall r>0 \ B(x;r)\cap A\neq\varnothing$. But $x\in B$ also so $B(x;r)\cap A\cap B\neq \varnothing$. Since $r$ was arbitrary, $x\in\overline{A\cap B}$.

Comment: Your error was trying to fit your question in the title. The goal of the title should be to give an impression of the kind of question, and you can put the full version of the question in the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof linked is correct. You can replace 'For some $s$...' with 'for all $s$...' and the logic goes through, so $s$ can indeed be taken to be arbitrary.

The incorrect assumption in your proof is that, if $B_r(x) \cap A \neq \emptyset$ and $B_r(x) \cap B \neq \emptyset$, then $B_r(x) \cap A \cap B \neq \emptyset$. If $B$ is not open, then these two nonempty sets can be disjoint, as illustrated by the case where $n = 1$, $B = [-1, 0]$, $A = (0, 1)$, $x = 0$, and $r = \frac{1}{2}$ (drawing this might be helpful).

Comment: How does the proof work if $s>r$? Couldn't it then be the case that $B_r(x)\cap A\cap B\neq\varnothing$?

Comment: If $s > r$, then  $B_s(x)$ contains $B_r(x)$. Therefore $B_s(x) \cap A \cap B$ contains $B_r(x) \cap A \cap B$. The latter is nonempty, and therefore so is the former.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to develop it more. For example, point out that if B is an open set then there is an open ball that contains $x$ and is contained in $B$.

**My suggestion**:

Let $x \in \overline{A} \cap B$. How $x \in \overline{A}$, then for every $\varepsilon > 0$, we have that

$$B(x; \varepsilon) \cap A \ne \emptyset.$$

How $B$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then exists $r > 0$ such that

$$x \in B(x;r) \subset B.$$

Then $x \in \overline{A \cap B}$ because for every $\varepsilon' > 0$ we have that

$$B(x;\varepsilon') \cap A \ne \emptyset,$$

and

$$B(x; \varepsilon') \cap B \ne \emptyset.$$

**Just note that** if $\varepsilon' > r$, then

$$B(x;r) \subset B(x; \varepsilon') \Rightarrow B(x; \varepsilon') \cap B \ne \emptyset.$$

On the other hand, if $\varepsilon < r$ then

$$x \in B(x;\varepsilon') \cap B$$.